# How can I detect which app made that beep?

Tags: console, alert, macos

I've got some weird beeps coming intermittently from my computer, and I don't know what is causing them.

Several minutes passed between each occurrence, and they've only happened twice so far, so troubleshooting by turning off apps and menu helpers could take a long time, and might be fruitless.

I looked for something in one of the logs in the Console app, but I didn't see anything.

Is there any way to detect or lookup in a log what app sent alert noises?  Is there any central point in the OS that controls this?  If it is not possible to do this after the fact, would it be possible to create an app that monitors and  logs this information, for just this situation?

#### Update

I'm using a MacBook Air (M1, 2020) running macOS 12.6.

When I said "I don't know what is causing them", I don't mean that I don't know the *physical* origin of the sound waves.  They are unquestionably coming from the speakers. (Rather they were.  They have not recurred since posting this question--which is why troubleshooting would be extremely difficult.) I mean that I don't know the app that is causing them.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the model of Mac, the version of macOS, etc. Some noises are mechanical, like a spinning HD which is failing, or [some other issue](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/macbook-air-beep-randomly-36910.html). If you have the time and inclination, plug in a set of headphones/earbuds and set the system volume low or off. If you still hear the beeps, then it is clearly not coming from the speakers.

Comment: Hmm - someone figured this for microphone and camera but I’m not sure they cover audio   - https://obdev.at/products/microsnitch/index.html